# Bootstrap panel in 2 column formation as part of a 3 column layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I am trying to create a grid layout using Bootstrap where there is a left-hand side, vertical navbar occupying 1/3 of the viewport on large devices, and the remaining 2/3 is split into two columns that contain panels. On mobile devices I want these panels to collapse into a single column, and the vertical navbar turn into the standard mobile collapsing navbar. Additionally, I want the logo at the top of the site to move to the left, above the side navbar (the images below illustrate a mockup of how I want it to look).

[Intended layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBa95.jpg)

At the moment I have set up the mobile collapse navbar and am happy with how it works in portrait and landscape, but am unsure what I need to change to make it transform to a vertical, left navbar for md, lg and xl devices, and for the logo to move to the left. I attempted to create a duplicate navbar of the one I had made for mobile, and at the same time hide the original I had created using a media query. Then I split up the panels into two separate rows and set each of their col values as `col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4`. I've also tried using a float but that didn't seem to work either. Here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">home</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#submit">submit</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#mailing">mailing list</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/">store</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="starter-template">
            <div class="center-block">
                <img src='img/sofa-logo.png' class="img-responsive center-block" alt="UQ SoFA logo">
            </div>
            <!-- /.center-block -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#submit">submit</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#mailing">mailing list</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
                          </li>
                          <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/">store</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">SoFA at Market Day</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">Cut Thumb ARI</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">Interview with...</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lecture by...</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row-->
```

[Here is a link to a codepen preview of my project.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBZeoq)

I feel as though I should be using only one navbar and not a media query to hide the original. Essentially I am stuck as to how to go about positioning these two columns of panels onto the right hand side and have the navbar and logo on the left, that then changes to the standard collapsing navbar and a single column for mobile devices. Any help as to how I can get this layout to look like my mockups would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how about this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqLQxg

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqLQxg)

```
<div class="background">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">home</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#submit">submit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#mailing">mailing list</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/">store</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="starter-template">
                <div class="center-block">
                    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/UlAJQv9.png' class="img-responsive center-block" alt="UQ SoFA logo">
                </div>
                <!-- /.center-block -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#about">about</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#blog">blog posts</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#submit">submit</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#events">events</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#mailing">mailing list</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="http://uqsofa.bigcartel.com/">store</a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.collapse navbar-collapse -->
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.col-xs-0 col-sm-0 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 -->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">SoFA at Market Day</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">Cut Thumb ARI</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">Interview with...</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">Lecture by...</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel panel-default-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row-->
            </div>
            <!-- /.starter-template-->

        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </div>
```